# Why auxiliary flag is 0 when there is a borrow between nibbles

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bcd, eflags

Testing on EMU8086, with the following code snippet:

```
MOV CX, 1527H
SUB CX, 44H
```

The emulator shows that AF is 0

```
   1527
 -   44
========
   14E3
```

When doing the subtraction by hand, we got 7 - 4 = 3, no problem here.
Then 2 - 4, we then have to borrow from the next nibble. So from my understanding, AF should have been 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AF is set according to carry (or borrow) from bit #3 to bit #4.  i.e. across the lowest / least-significant nibble boundary, the one in the middle of AL/BL/CL/DL, not the middle of AX.  (Since each hex digit represents a nibble, carry/borrow from the lowest hex digit into the 2nd-lowest.)

As you say `7h - 3h` doesn't borrow, so AF=0.

The description of AF as a "half-carry" flag makes sense in the context of byte operand-size, where there's only one nibble boundary within the byte, and it's half-way to the carry-out position.

Word operand-size (and larger on 386 and x86-64) still sets AF from bit 3->4, not from the middle of the operand-size or carry between any other bit-positions.

---

That's because it's intended for packed and unpacked BCD operations like DAA and AAA respectively.  Note that AAA (for use after `add ax, cx` or whatever with 2 decimal digits unpacked into separate bytes) depends on AF detecting carry-out from the low 4 bits.  There would never be carry from bit #7 to bit #8 (across the byte boundary) in that case, e.g. `0x0909` + `0x0909` produces `0x1212`, with an AF-setting carry from `9+9 = 12h`, but no carry from `09h + 09h = 12h` at the byte boundary.

Instead of working differently for unpacked (checking the high bits of AL), `AAA` uses mostly the same logic as for DAA (checking AF, and low nibble of `al` being > 9) - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aaa#operation

Fun fact: you can [use `DAS` to save a couple bytes in int -> ASCII-hex conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193793/little-endian-number-to-string-conversion/193842#193842), along with cmp and sbb, a total hack / abuse that just happens to work because of the distance between the ASCII codes for `'9'` and `'A'`, along with DAS's conditional `AL-=6` and other behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! By "bit 3->4" I assume you mean hex digit (not a binary digit), right?
So the AF is set when there is a carry/borrow between the first and second hex digits, or between the third and forth hex digits, but not between the second and third hex digits?

Comment: Hmm, I tried `MOV CX, 1527H`, `SUB CX, 1622H`, which didn't set the AF. This doesn't seem to match my understanding of the answer. :(

Comment: @Youssef13  Yes, each hex digit represents a nibble, so carry from the lowest hex digit to the 2nd.  `7h - 2h` doesn't borrow either.

Comment: @Youssef13: x86 numbers bits from 0 = least significant to 7, 15, 31, or 63 = most significant. (Like all sane ISAs, i.e. not including PowerPC :P).  Bit #3 is the one set by `bts eax, 3`, or the one you get from `mov ax, 1` / `shl ax, 3`.  It's the high bit of the least significant nibble.  When I said *bit* I meant bit, not nibble or hex digit.